# matrices statements problem.

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices. Which of the following statements are always true?

(i) $(AB)^2 = A^2 B^2$

(ii) if the homogeneous system $Ax = 0$ has infinitely many solutions then $A$ is not invertible.

(iii) if $AB = AC$ then $B = C$

(A) (iii) only
(B) (i) and (iii) only
(C) (ii) only
 (D) (i) only
 (E) (ii) and (iii) only
(F) none of them
 (G) (i) and (ii) only
 (H) all of them

I learned in class, I think (i) is not true, I chose answer E and A, but both are wrong. Please help!

Comment: @AnuragA it would be helpful if you could write this as an answer (so that the question is taken off the unanswered queue).  Note also that this solution corresponds to choice (c).

Answer (score 0):

**At Omnomnomnom's suggestion** I am writing my comment as an answer.

Only (ii) is correct. Without commutativity (i) need not be true in general and without invertibility (iii) need not be true in general.

The reason (ii) holds is because there is a non-zero solution to the homogeneous system, hence non-trivial null space, hence not invertible. Thus the only answer that holds is (C).